# How to detect which account is sending spam

Tags: postfix

I manage a postfix SMTP server on a college. Every week at least one account is compromised and used to send spam. We developed an in-house monitor that suspend any local account that has more than 40 messages in queue. In this way we have stopped sending spam at the first moments.

But yesterday some attacker compromised an account and could send mails thru our server. The monitor couldn't detect it because the messages weren't queued using our domain, but info@googlemail.com.

How can I discover which account was sending mails using this address?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have a sequence of compromises and not one big clusterproblem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` one of the `QUEUEID`s in your maillog. You should see something like:

```
May 20 15:25:40 mta2 postfix/smtps/smtpd[26154]: 578C7E0013: client=unknown[203.0.113.3], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=someuser
May 20 15:25:40 mta2 postfix/qmgr[3291]: 578C7E0013: from=<info@googlemail.com>, size=1198, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 20 15:25:40 mta2 postfix/smtp[26074]: 578C7E0013: to=<targetaddress@example.com>, relay=mx.example.com[98.51.100.14]:25, delay=0.15, delays=0.02/0.01/0.06/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6B87C336809C)
```

`sasl_username` is the part you are looking for.

---

**In future**, you'll want to set [`reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch) as part of your [`smtpd_sender_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions). This requires a valid [`smtpd_sender_login_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps). You may also want to check out [`policyd`](http://www.policyd.org/) in addition to or as a replacement for your homegrown monitor.

---

**Example:**

```
**main.cf**  
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch
smtpd_sender_login_maps = ldap:$config_directory/ldap-sender-login-map.cf  

**ldap-sender-login-map.cf**
version = 3
server_host = ldap://ldap.example.com/
search_base = dc=example,dc=com
query_filter = mailLocalAddress=%s
result_attribute = mailLocalAddress
result_format = %s,%u
```